# How to handle X-HTTP-Method-Override in cfx?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Hi i am using cfx for my rest service. i have created a rest method `@Path("request/{requestId}/")
    @POST
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String approveDigiCertRequest() {
        //logic
    }`
when the client is calling this method it is using the http header"X-HTTP-Method-Override" its value is set to approve
when i try hitting my rest from the client i am getting an error as no method with type approve. I think it is looking for a method annotated with approve.
How do i handle this scenario. Is proceeding with interceptors a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the details of CFX interceptors, but I have done a similar thing very recently using a `javax.servlet.Filter` and a custom subclass of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that's overriding `getMethod` in order to return the overridden request method extracted from the header.

For inspiration you might want to check http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java, which is conceptually very similar but obviously will require some changes in order to get the right header attribute an replace the Spring specific stuff.